# Json Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, json

recent_json & historic_json Function Returns:

```
return(frame.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Main Function:

```
recentdata = recent_json(station)
historicdata = historic_json(station)
alldata = historicdata + recentdata
```

How can i add the data to the same `json?` The data has a break in it.

e.g :

```
"Relative_Humidity":93.0}][{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1526774400000,
```

The `][` shouldn't be there. This is the place which historic data ends and recent data begin.
It is probably due to me concatenating them wrong. How can i truly concatenate them and show as one main `json` file like:

```
[{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1356998400000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.4,"Relative_Humidity":91.0},

{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1357002000000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.3,"Relative_Humidity":93.0}]
```

Comment: Seems like you are concatenating Strings rather than merging two arrays together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to be aware that your `to_json` actually outputs strings. That said, you can use string manipulation to achieve your goal. The closing bracket is the last character of your first string and the opening bracket is the first character of your second string, so doing

```
alldata = historicdata[:-1] + ',' + recentdata[1:]
```

will give you your desired output **as a string**. You'll need to pass it to e.g. [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to actually transform it to a Python object that can be accessed and worked with in conventional ways

Comment: It recognizes the output as a list, so json.loads() does not work, instead doing json.dumps() on the all data results in something like : 

```[{\"STATIONS_ID\":\"44\",\"Date\":1356998400000,\"Quality_Level\":3,\"Air_Temperature\":8.4,\"Relative_Humidity\":91.0}, . . . 
```

Comment: `json.loads` worked fine for me given the output you provided in your question. Can you share your string and the error message you get from `json.loads`?

Comment: ```new = json.loads(alldata)
        return func.HttpResponse(new, mimetype='application/json')```
Exception: TypeError: reponse is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got list

Comment: Do you transform `alldata` between the concatenation step I proposed and the call to `json.loads`? There is no way my line returns anything but a string

Comment: Nope, just these two lines together after each other. Weird.

Comment: Can you try to wipe your working environment and run the script from scratch? I cannot believe this would not work